# Binary comparison of images/files using MSBuild or CCNet

Tags: msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

At my current client, we are using CruiseControl.Net for continuous integration. We are building website projects using MSBuild.

The issue that I have run up against is the following: We want to move all code and associated DLLs with every release. However, we also have (sometimes) hundreds of megs of files and images that are unchanged. In the CC.Net world, I will probably split these in to two different builds, one for a site and the other for static content.

**What I would like to know is if anyone knows of an MSBuild or CCNet plugin that will allow me to do a binary diff on my static content?** I'd like to be able to know if an image has chnaged or been added and then package *only* the changed/added content up and push them to a QA environment.

Answer (score 0):

I did that with svn logs and MsBuild tasks.

Every time I Deploy the website, I save somewhere the revision number (basically in a flat file).
Then at the next Build-Deploy, I will do a svn log to see the diff between the latest release and now. Then my MsBuild Task takes the svn log xml output, parses it and outputs in another file the interesting static files added/modified/deleted.
Then the usual tasks come in and process only the modified files instead of every file.

That was a huge piece of work (above all with internal logic : our "static" contents are dynamically generated for each environment, each partner and each theme) but it was worth it.

Either way, you can try using a ChecksumCopy, but I don't know if it's less expensive...